# Is there a way to deal with 'java: bad operand types for binary operator '!='' in this piece of code?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this code and it is coming up with the following error:

> java: bad operand types for binary operator '!='   first type:  Node
> second type: int

It is suppose to have the head be 3 and the next Node have data 4. Then the while loop is suppose to print each data from each Node.

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
    }


    Node appendToTail(int d) {
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
        return end;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node t;
        Node obj = new Node(3);
        t = obj.appendToTail(4);
        while (t != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(t);
            

        }
    }
}
```

////

```
Expected output:

3 4
```

Comment: while (t != 0) this doesn't make sense ... at all. Did you perhaps mean while (t.data != 0)

Comment: 0 can be NULL. Basically, when there is no other node.

Comment: 0 can be NULL, no, it can't. 0 is a value, NULL is lack of a value. Also, 0 is a primitive (int) NULL can only be for objects

Comment: An `int` can **never** be `null` in Java.  The `int` type is a primitive type, not a reference types.  The value `null` is only legal for reference types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code, even if fixed, would result in an infinite loop, because once the while loop is entered, its condition does not change.

I think you want:

```
while (t != null)
```

but that doesn't solve the infinite loop problem.

To have code that behaves as you expect:

```
for (t = obj; t != null; t = t.next) {
    System.out.println(t.data);
}
```

Comment: Bingo! This is it.